# How to order by current and previous values two rows in a SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I'm currently working on a dataset in which I have airport destinations in a SQL table. I originally tried using the `lag` function to populate each row with the previous rows' destinations then using multiple order by's but am stuck on how to order this properly. Below is a small example where the third row should be in the 2nd position in the table. Below is a brief overview of the current code and then an example data table.

```
select *,
lag(start,1) over(partition by ID) as last_start_stage
lag(finish,1) over(partition by ID) as last_finish_stage
from data
order by ID, start = last_finish_stage
```

| ID | start | finish |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | NULL | DAL |
| A | BOS | CAL |
| A | DAL | BOS |

**Notes**

*Null is always the starting location which I have accounted for.

*A row's current start value must correspond to the previous rows finish value

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Sql server and mysql are two different database products. Removed the conflicting product tags. Please, add the one back that you are actually using!

Comment: SQL table has no row order, so there's no either relative row position or ordinal row position. You need to provide sample data and ordering criteria. The syntax of your query looks wrong because relative functions require `order by` clause that is missing. And tag only one DBMS: SQL Server is not MySQL and vice versa

Answer (score 1):

If you think of these as parent-child relationships, then use a recursive query to walk the tree, adding a level number for each leg.  Then you can use that level number in the final Order By.

```
With Recursive leglevel as (
    Select ID, start, finish, 0 as level
    From journey_leg
    Where start is null
Union All
    Select b.ID, b.start, b.finish, a.level+1 as level
    From leglevel a inner join journey_leg b On a.id=b.id and a.finish=b.start
)
Select ID, start, finish from leglevel
Order By ID, level
```

The syntax for each database system is slightly different: in Sql Server you would omit the Recursive phrase.  This was tested in PostgreSQL.  Obviously, if you have journey_legs that fail to connect properly they will be omitted from this query.